# Signification de "rien que [sujet] [verbe]"

Tags: expressions, paroles-de-chanson

Dans plusieurs chansons de Gringe, j'ai rencontré l'expression "*rien que [sujet][verbe]*", et j'ai aucune idée de ce que ça veut dire.

Vu que c'est une même personne qui l'utilise plusieurs fois, j'imagine que c'est une expression un peu rare mais qui existe (pas juste une fantaisie utilisée une seule fois). Régional peut-être ?

Dans Déchiré ([paroles](https://genius.com/Gringe-dechire-lyrics)) on a :

> Et **rien que tu brasses** du vent, et **rien que tu gagnes** du temps

Et dans Pour la nuit ([paroles](https://genius.com/Gringe-pour-la-nuit-lyrics)) :

> On tombe à la renverse, mais **rien qu'on tombe** ensemble

J'ai cherché mais j'ai pas trouvé grand chose, "*rien que*" est déjà une expression qui veut dire autre chose.

Answer (score 4):

> Et rien que tu brasses du vent, et rien que tu gagnes du temps

Comme aCOSwt l'expliquait, il s'agit ici d'une contraction d'une phrase plus longue.

> Et tu ne fais rien d'autre que brasser du vent, et tu ne fais rien d'autre que gagner du temps.

Ce qui donne "Et tu ne fais rien que brasser du vent" puis "Et rien que tu brasses du vent". La phrase devient plus courte, plus percutante, et met au premier plan le mot "rien", qui est la **seule** chose que fait finalement la personne désignée par "tu"...

> On tombe à la renverse, mais rien qu'on tombe ensemble

Pour celle-ci, j'ai dû me plonger dans les paroles afin d'essayer de comprendre le contexte (deux personnes en relation instable, basée sur le charnel puisque la relation émotionnelle a cessé de fonctionner suite à une infidélité). J'ai déterminé plusieurs sens possibles :

> - "On ne tombe rien ensemble" : on ne parvient à faire tomber aucune difficulté ensemble
> - "On ne demande rien de plus que de tomber à la renverse ensemble" : seules les relations sexuelles avec l'autre nous intéressent. Je favoriserai cette interprétation car elle concorde avec les contractions de phrases évoquées plus haut : "on ne demande rien de plus que tomber ensemble", "on ne demande rien que tomber ensemble", "rien qu'on tombe ensemble".

Je n'ai jamais rencontré de tournures de phrases telles que celles-ci en dehors de Gringe.

Answer (score 0):

Tu viens ici nous apprendre des scoops, cependant, ce n'est un scoop pour personne. De cela, *Je*, mais aussi, *il, nous, elles* et donc pourquoi pas *on*, pourraient dire :

*Rien qu'on ne sache déjà!*

Laisse tomber le *ne* explétif : *Rien qu'on sache déjà*

Laisse ensuite *béton* ;-)  le subjonctif : *Rien qu'on sait déjà*

On peut changer de verbe sur le même propos. Il n'y a rien dans tes scoops qui nous fasse tomber sur le cul, en suivant le même procès que ci-dessus -> *Rien qu'on tombe sur le cul.*

Après, cela dit que je suis pas poète et encore moins... dans ce genre-là et donc... que *rien qu'j'en sais en fait* ;-)

Comment: C'est une expression que tu connais ou c'est ton interprétation ? Quel sens tu donnerait à "*Rien qu'on tombe ensemble*" ?

Comment: D'ailleurs j'ai modifié ma question mais ce n'est pas spécifique à "*on*" ("*rien que tu gagnes du temps*"). Et je ne pense vraiment pas que ce soit une figure de style particulière spécifique au rap.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat : 100% Mon interprétation partant d'une phrase que 100% je connais à laquelle j'ai appliqué un procès que 100% je connais et sais appliqué souvent.

Comment: Mais ça n'a pas de sens pour mes exemples ! Parce que soit le verbe est intransitif comme tomber (ça peut pas être une déformation de "*on tombe rien*"), soit il est transitif mais il a déjà un complément ("*rien qu'on brasse du vent*", et pas "*rien qu'on brasse*", qui lui peut vouloir dire "*on brasse rien*")

Comment: @TeleportingGoat : Je ne nierai en aucun cas que cela puisse ne pas faire sens. Maintenant... la transitivité des verbes et les arguments qui reposent dessus... en fouillant un peu ici, tu trouveras ce que j'en pense...! Cela dit... oui encore ce n'est que mon interprétation gouvernée par, je le reconnais un a priori : la facilité! Après... évidemment... il est de droit ici de considérer la licence poétique. Et là... le sens... c'est **toi, moi** qui le trouvons... ou pas! Ça t'cause ou... Ça t'cause pas! Moi... sur ce sujet... comme écrit dans la réponse... je laisse maintenant... béton! ;-)

Comment: Sans blague ? C'est des paroles à 2 balles et je réponds de la même marnière : Pas de quoi un faire un fromage. Juste de quoi faire une chanson. ;)